# Does the Google Play app always updates automatically?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I use Android 4.0.4 (Cyanogenmod) and I have the habit of disabling automatic updates for all my apps. I have noticed the Google Play app seems to update itself automatically -- when there are updates for any other app, I'm shown a notification mesage from the Google Play app, and I have to use it in order to update the app. But when there are updates for Google Play, it seems to autoupdate itself. Is it true? Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Section 3 of the [Google Play Terms of Service](http://play.google.com/about/play-terms.html) you consent to Automatic Updates:

> Updates. You may need to install updates to Google Play or related Google software that we introduce from time to time to use Google Play and to access or download Products. Products originating from Google may communicate with Google servers from time to time to check for available updates to the Products and to the functionality of Google Play, such as bug fixes, patches, enhanced functions, missing plug-ins and new versions (collectively, "Updates"). **By using the Google Play store and installing these Products, you agree to such automatically requested and received Updates.**

*Bolding added for emphasis.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the Google Play Store does self-update itself.

As far as I know, there is no way to disable the auto-self-updating of the Play Store application as it is built into the application/system's code. You might could try freezing it with Titanium Backup (requires root), but I don't know if that would work since the Play Store is also integrated into the OS. The only sure way would be to disable all internet connectivity.

Is there a specific reason that you want to disable this feature?

Comment: Guess one could fool it using some Tasker-tricks or making the local `*.apk` (in `/data/data/`) read-only -- but I wouldn't bet my right hand on that :)

Comment: Nah, no specific reason, just being geekily curious ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to disable updates of your Google Play application, but it's not secured. It's possible for you to have problems updating your market when you decide you want.

If you want to try, this is what you have to do:

- You have to root you device
- Install Link2SD
- Open Link2SD
- Click on the Play Store update
- Select actions
- Convert to system app
- **Reboot immediately**

Read more [here](http://androidforums.com/optimus-v-all-things-root/569471-uninstall-google-play-updates.html).

Comment: This works? Isn't Google Play Store already a system app?

Comment: @BryanDenny You may be right. I have not tested this answer and just accepted it based on many positive answers on the linked forum. I will check if the Play app is already a system app on my CM 4.0.4 phone.

Comment: I have checked and indeed, the Play Store app is already a system app, there's no point in converting it to a system app.

Comment: Google Play *is* a system app. If you are rooted, you can make it a user app by uninstalling it and installing it again. (You can make a backup of the original, so you'll have installation APK, or you can install any version really). But even as a user app, it *still* automatically updates itself. I tested this.